# Raspberry Pi RT Preempt Linux Kernel Build Error

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, compiling, real-time

I am trying to Build and install a Raspberry Pi RT Preempt Linux Kernel.

These are the steps that I had followed:

1. I installed the pre-compiled kernel kernel-4.4.9-rt17.tgz
2. I downloaded Raspberry Pi kernel sources and applied the Real Time patch-4.4.9-rt17.patch.gz.(I followed [this link](http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203) for installation )
3. I configured my kernel for Raspberry Pi3,Model B using :

   ```
   export KERNEL=kernel7

   make bcm2709_defconfig
   ```
4. I configured the kernel to support Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) using

   ```
   make -j$(nproc) menuconfig
   ```
5. I build the kernel using

   ```
   make -j$(nproc) zImage
   ```

   but I  received the error:

   ```
   In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:0:
   ./include/linux/sched.h:2040:32: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token
   define tsk_cpus_allowed(tsk) (&(tsk)->cpus_allowed) ^     ./include/linux/sched.h:3679:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘tsk_cpus_allowed’
   static inline const struct cpumask *tsk_cpus_allowed(struct task_struct *p) ^ In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:0:
   ./include/linux/sched.h:3687:19: error: redefinition of ‘tsk_nr_cpus_allowed’     static inline int tsk_nr_cpus_allowed(struct task_struct *p) ^ In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:0:  ./include/linux/sched.h:2042:19: note: previous definition of ‘tsk_nr_cpus_allowed’ was here
   ```

[image: Here is the kernel build output]

Do you have any idea to solve this? I don't know what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate any help.